# Sprites is not getting assigned to the material

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

For creating a background scrolling for my game, I created a quad(3D object) gameobject and a material and assigned the material to the gameobject. Then I got the background sprite for my game and attached it to the material in the albedo section. But the material shows like the sprite is not assigned at all. The material is still violet in colour. What settings am I missing and what option did I get wrong. Please help me. I have attached the screenshot of sprite and material settings in the inspector. For background scrolling, I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXNXEIwOLMA.
[MaterialInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h2Xo.png)
[SpriteInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z876O.png)

Comment: I am glad I could help. Could you also select my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to do it for your use case. Follow these steps:

1- Select your sprite and change the texture type to `Sprite (2D and UI)`.

2- Add a `Sprite Renderer` component to your quad. Then, select your image for the Sprite section of `Sprite Renderer` component.

You see a violet color when the shader pipeline has an error or something is broken with the rendering, which is the case here for you. If you do the steps above it should work though.

Comment: isnt quad a 3D object. So can we add a sprite renderer to a 3d object?

Comment: Yes, you can do that regardless whether it is 2D or 3D. By the way, quads are also 3D objects as far as I know :)